# VPN PPTP (MPPE) - connection freeze after while

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, pptp

I have configured VPN (PPTP) connection  (configured as in screenshot) and I'm experiencing this issue (ubuntu 12.10):

The connection works fine, I can browse web and access local content, however after sometime it freeze ( also ping a local address doesn't give answer anymore ) and the only way to re-enable the connection is to stop it and restart it

**UPDATE:**
I have noticed in `var/log/syslog` that when the connection freezes those messages starts to be logged:

```
 pppd[8268]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'IP6 Header Compression' (0x4f)
 pppd[8268]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0x1c18
 pppd[8268]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 0xb9
 pppd[8268]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'RTP IPHC Full Header' (0x61)
 pppd[8268]: Protocol-Reject for unsupported protocol 'KNX Bridging Control Protocol'
```

The issue looks like this one:

http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.protocols.ppp/2007-01/msg00010.html

And here looks as well documented 
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=427825

Settings :

[image: Settings]

Comment: Does [this solution](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#lcp_protrej_1) apply to your case?

Comment: looking into it, I will let you know

Comment: (1) Do you need IPv6 over PPTP? Disable IPv6 if not needed. (2) Uncheck `MSCHAP`. Let me know if that works and move to answer.

Comment: I have fixed it upgrading pptp-linux package with the one on debian sid ... but now it is back again

Answer (score 1):

According to http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#connections_freeze it could be an MTU issue, so try setting your MTU to a lower value (e.g. 1400).